# Is there a Dart equivalent of Python's all() method?

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a method that returns `true` if a function `test`, given an element, returns `true` for every element of an `Iterable`, or in my case a `List`, similar to Python's `all()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking is the [every](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/Iterable/every.html) method.

```
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var evenNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

  print(numbers.every((n) => n.isEven)); //false
  print(evenNumbers.every((n) => n.isEven)); //true
```

Answer (score 3):

[Iterable#every](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/Iterable/every.html)

> Checks whether every element of this iterable satisfies test.

```dart
void main() {
  print([1, 2, 3].every((i) => i > 0));
}
```